# Control Remote Terminal Services from my application

Tags: c#, terminal

I want my application to connect to Remote Desktop (Windows 2008 R2 Terminal) with my credentials and access the network/applications there.

I have seen how to use the ActiveX library to put the object of terminal services to create the Tabbed RPD client; it is nice but I need to CONTROL and access it easily without doing it with some simple Auto-it-user-simulating-copy/pasting-application.

At work, we use the terminal desktop service of other company's network. There are guys who have a lot of tables and tickets to do, but they can't fully automate it as it's in separate working environment -> can I access it via my app or not? Is it that tight and secure?